# Can't connect to database in vb.net

Tags: c#, mysql, vb.net

Keeps throwing the exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in MySql.Data.dll

here is the code:

```
 Public Sub showWorkerFullnames()

    getQuery = "SELECT worker.worker_fullname FROM worker"
    getCommand = New MySqlCommand(getQuery, MySQLConnection)
    getReader = getCommand.ExecuteReader

    cbWorkerFullnames.Items.Clear()

    While getReader.Read

        cbWorkerFullnames.Items.Add(getReader.Item("worker_fullname").ToString)

    End While
```

Comment: `MySQLConnection` is a type - you need to create an instance, provide a connection string and open the connection instance.

Comment: am new to this..how do I go by it??

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-sql-command.html) shows a working example.

Creating a connection:

```
string connStr = 
    "server=localhost;user=root;database=world;port=3306;password=******;";
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
```

Use that connection object when creating the command:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
```

Open the connection before using it. The linked example opens the connection right after creating it. It's hair-splitting, but I would make opening the connection the very last thing before using it.

```
conn.Open();
```

And don't forget to close the connection when you're done.